# Cant export correctly from blender to unity because of the mirror modyfier

Tags: modeling, export, unity, mirror-modifier

I've been working on my own game in unity and I modelled some cars in blender. I tried to export it without applied modyfiers and unjoined objects and it worked just fine. But when I applied the mirror modyfier and joined the parts of every cars together, its not exported correctly to unity. Is there something I can do?

[image: blender_screenshot]
[image: unity_screenshot]

Comment: It's a little hard to tell what's going on in your screenshots and what you see as being incorrect.  Please crop your screenshots to show only the relevant parts and add a little explanation of what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

From the appearance of the backwards car in unity, I would say your normals are oriented backwards and thus only viewing faces from the inside causes them to appear. Recalculate the normals outside.

Comment: thanks. worked perfectly.